# How to change default values of td in table HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

How can i resize only 1 or 2 cells from my table. I created a new class with new width , but when i try to use it nothing changes. Where is mistake in my code ? 
So the problem is that i want City and State to be on the same line with shorter width of the cells, because now the input box of State is upper the Last name and it's not in the table

CSS

```css
<style> 
    table {
        width: auto;
    }

    table,th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    td {
        width: 300px !important;
    }

    th {
        width: 120px !important;
        text-align: right;
    }

    .thnewclass {
        width: 50px;
    }

    .cbCell {
        width: 15px;
    }

    input[type="text"] {
        width: 270px;
        !important;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<table>
    <tr> 
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <td class="cbCell">
            <input type = "text" name "Last Name" value = "Enter Last Name" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <td> 
            <input type = "text" name "First Name" value = "Enter First Name" /> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Address</th>
        <td> <input type = "text" name "Address" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class = "thnewclass">City</th>
        <td class = "thnewclass">
            <input type = "text" name "City" />
        </td> 
        <th>State</th> 
        <input type = "text" name "State">
    </tr>
```

Comment: Table cell sizing is *highly* dependant on the context of the rest of the table. You need to provide a real [mcve]. Ideally as a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 1):

Loose the `!important` from td style

```
td {
    width: 300px ;
}
th {
    width: 120px;
    text-align: right;
}
.thnewclass {
    width: 50px;
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/abkjgp2z/)**